# Why blacksmiths and armorers no longer appear in the World Map?

Tags: ps4, the-witcher-3

In the beginning of the game, Blacksmiths and Armorers used to appear on the World Map, however for a while now they don't appear there anymore, just on the mini-map when they're nearby, which isn't very useful.

**Why did it happen?** 
**Is there a way to bring them back?**

If it matters, I'm playing the **PS4** version.

Comment: I see some of them, they often seem to be hidden if there is a Grindstone or Armorer's Table at the same location (which there usually is in villages), do you see the grindstone/table icons? Also check the map filters!

Comment: @greg-449 thanks, actually I noticed this myself and already have the grindstones and armoer tables hidden with those very filters.

Comment: I see the same problem on the PC (Steam) version of the game.  Interestingly, the icons for specific armorers/blacksmiths appear on the map if I've recently visited them, but they don't tend to stick around indefinitely.  I don't know why this changed, or how to fix it.

Comment: @Liesmith exactly, also noticed they appear when I'm nearby,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed as part of **patch 1.2** of the game.